# .appendTo() does not work in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, appendto

## I have updated my example

My case has two steps:

1) User will select the Number of modeled stages from a drop-down list.
2) Based on users input, I am using .appendTo method to create HTML tables on the fly.

Everything goes well on chrome, firefox, IE9 except IE7. A number of my users have IE7 and they are not allowed to update. So I have to fix this issue. Really appreciate any comments.

## Another interesting thing is that I have used .appendTo() created another [webpage](http://www.ubertool.org/przm_input.html), which works in IE7.

Here is an example of how it [looks](http://jsfiddle.net/HmHkr/1/) in Chrome and IE9

Below is my code:

HTML code:

```
<div class="articles">
<table align="center">
<tr><th><label for="id_S">Number of modeled stages:</label></th><td><select name="S" id="id_S">
<option value="">Please choose</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
</select></td></tr>
</table></div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
$(".articles").find('table').addClass('table');

$('#id_S').change(function() {
    $('.leslie').remove();
    $('.no').remove();
    var total = $(this).val()
    $('<table class="leslie" border="0" align="center"><tr><th width="5" colspan=' + total + '>Lesile Matrix:</th></tr>').appendTo('.table');

    i = 0
    while (i < total) {
        $('<tr>').appendTo('.leslie')

        var j = 0
        while (j < total) {
            $('<td><input type="text" size="5" name="a' + i + '' + j + '" value="0" id="id_a' + i + '' + j + '"/></td>').appendTo('.leslie tr:last')
            j = j + 1
        }

        $('</tr>').appendTo('.leslie')
        i = i + 1
    }
    $('</table>').appendTo('.leslie');


    $('<table class="no" border="0" align="center"><tr><th width="5">Initial Number:</th></tr>').appendTo('.leslie');

    q = 0
    while (q < total) {
        $('<tr><td><input type="text" size="5" name="no' + q + '" value="0" id="id_a' + q + '"/></td></tr>').appendTo('.no')
        q = q + 1
    }
    $('</table>').appendTo('.no');

})​
```

Comment: Unfortunately, a *lot* of things don't work in IE7 ... and if you ask me, all web standards are one of those things. I feel bad that you have to support IE7.

Comment: Something similar was already answered here:

[jquery bug appendTo in IE7][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200937/jquery-bug-appendto-not-working-in-ie7

Comment: @Linuxios: thanks for the comment. Is there a list or summary for the unsupported features in IE7?

Comment: @tao.hong I think the list of supported features is shorter.

Comment: I would highly recommend reading more about dom manipulation in jQuery; the way you're creating this table is highly inefficient, not to mention `$('</table>')` is not doing what you think it is.

Comment: @tao.hong: That's a good question. I don't know of one, but I bet someone might have tried. I think the problem is that it isn't so much big unsupported features, but little things in certain circumstances that make problems.

Comment: You're using `.appendTo()` incorrectly.  It's not string concatenation, so using it to append closing tags is wrong.

Comment: tao.hong: What @jack is saying is the core of it. I don't think that this code would work on any browser, at least not if I know anything about jQuery.

Comment: You could try `$('.leslie').append('<table ...')`

Comment: @jmoerdyk: In your case, newer version of chrome and IE can correct my mistake automatically?  Could you please know how to fix this error?

Comment: @Linuxios, I did not put '</table>' in the thread. But in my code I have the close tag.

Comment: @Linuxios It would work in other browsers, it just won't produce the intended result, unless the intended result is a weird structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using DOM/jQuery correctly. The DOM (or jQuery which is a DOM wrapper with a mix of other stuff) cannot manipulate open and close tags separately, it can only manipulate them together. If you pass partial HTML into jQuery, it will use the DOM API to construct a DOM object. In your case, the IE7 DOM cannot figure out what your partial HTML means.

The following should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=" ../stylesheets/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script> 
<script>
$('<table class="leslie" border="0" align="center"><tr><th width="5">Lesile Matrix:</th></tr></table>').appendTo('.table');         
$('<tr>').appendTo('.leslie');
$('<td><input type="text" size="5" name="a" value="0" id="id_a"/></td>').appendTo('.leslie tr:last');
</script>
```

The premise is that when you call `$(...)` with HTML, you should always pass in valid HTML.

Comment: The reason of adding HTML object piece by piece is because its size (the number of tds and trs are controlled by a drop-down menu.

Comment: When you use jQuery, you have to think of elements on the page as whole objects, not open and close tags. You can still add stuff piece-by-piece, when you handle them as objects.

Comment: @tao.hong then loop through and create one html string, and append it all at once. That's the most efficient way to do it anyway.

Comment: you need to change your first `.appendTo` from `.appendTo('.table')` to something like  `.appendTo('.table td:last')`. In IE7, if you have `<table><table></table></table>`, the inner table is not rendered. It has to be `<table><tr><td><table></table></td></tr></table>`

Comment: Here is my forked version that works in IE9 emulate IE7-mode http://jsfiddle.net/AhYKJ/

Comment: @voidvector: the .'table' td:last' approach works! Thanks so much. BTW, how did you enable IE7 mode in jsfiddle?

Comment: It's part of the F12 dev toolbar function of IE9, not jsfiddle.

Comment: One more question. Is there a way to add a new table after the existing table in iE7? Something like <table></table><table></table>?

Comment: use .insertAfter('.table') instead of .appendTo('.table td:last')

Answer (score 7):

You can't append pieces of HTML like `<table>` and then separately `</table>`.  You must append whole working pieces of HTML that make fully formed objects.

`.append()` and `.appendTo()` make whole DOM objects and then append those.  They don't just append some HTML onto the end of innerHTML.

So, any HTML you pass `.appendTo()` must be a fully formed HTML object (e.g. an entire table or an entire row).

You can build up the HTML string yourself and then append that all at once:

```
var html = '<table class="leslie" border="0" align="center"><tr><th width="5">Lesile Matrix:</th></tr>';
html += '<tr><td><input type="text" size="5" name="a" value="0" id="id_a"/></td></tr>';
html += '</table>';
$(html).appendTo(document.body);
```

---

OK, I've taken your HTML and code and rewritten the code to build proper HTML objects.  I wasn't sure where you want the second table to be inserted since you were trying to append one table to another which isn't a legal structure.  But, in any case, here's the fixed up code:

```
$('#id_S').change(function() {
    // remove previous tables
    $('.leslie').remove();
    $('.no').remove();

    // construct 2-D table that is total x total in size
    var total = $(this).val()
    var newTable = $('<table class="leslie" border="0" align="center"><tr><th width="5" colspan=' + total + '>Lesile Matrix:</th></tr></table>');

    var i = 0;
    while (i < total) {
        // create new row
        var newRow = $('<tr>').appendTo(newTable);

        var j = 0;
        while (j < total) {
            // create new cell and append it to the current row
            $('<td><input type="text" size="5" name="a' + i + '' + j + '" value="0" id="id_a' + i + '' + j + '"/></td>').appendTo(newRow);
            j = j + 1;
        }
        // add this row to the table
        newRow.appendTo(newTable);
        i = i + 1;
    }
    // add the fully formed table to the document
    newTable.appendTo('.table');

    // create out second table
    newTable = $('<table class="no" border="0" align="center"><tr><th width="5">Initial Number:</th></tr></table>');

    var q = 0;
    while (q < total) {
        // create a new row and add it to the new table
        $('<tr><td><input type="text" size="5" name="no' + q + '" value="0" id="id_a' + q + '"/></td></tr>').appendTo(newTable);
        q = q + 1;
    }
    // add this fully formed table to the document
    newTable.appendTo(".table");

})​
```

And here's a working demo that works in IE7 too: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/35ZNF/

---

Or, here's a simpler version that just constructs the HTML into a string and then appends the HTML all at once:

```
$('#id_S').change(function() {
    // remove previous tables
    $('.leslie').remove();
    $('.no').remove();
    var total = $(this).val()

    // construct 2-D table that is total x total in size
    var html = '<table class="leslie" border="0" align="center"><tr><th width="5" colspan=' + total + '>Lesile Matrix:</th></tr>';
    for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        html += '<tr>';
        for (var j = 0; j < total; j++) {
            html += '<td><input type="text" size="5" name="a' + i + '' + j + '" value="0" id="id_a' + i + '' + j + '"/></td>';
        }
        html += '</tr>';
    }
    html += "</table>";
    $(".table").append(html);

    // create our second table
    html = '<table class="no" border="0" align="center"><tr><th width="5">Initial Number:</th></tr>';
    for (var q = 0; q < total; q++) {
        html += '<tr><td><input type="text" size="5" name="no' + q + '" value="0" id="id_a' + q + '"/></td></tr>';
    }
    html += '</table>';
    $(".table").append(html);
})​
```

Working demo of this version: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/qMnZV/

Comment: I see. But I think newer IE supports attaching elements of a HTML object. http://jsfiddle.net/DZ7Ha/

Comment: @tao.hong It's true IE supports attaching elements. But you still have to attach them correctly. The correct way of doing it is the way jfriend00 says, write the complete objects, i.e. with closed tags then attach. You can't attach part of an object then close it later.

Comment: @tao.hong - in your jsFiddle, the browser is trying to figure out what the heck you are doing by trying to create partial objects.  It can only make whole objects so it tries to guess what you're trying to do.  You will not get predictable behavior across browsers when you make it try to guess.

Comment: @tao.hong Also, using complex html in `$()` will result in headaches later on when jQuery tightens up that method in favor of using `$.parseHTML()` to create dom nodes from html strings.

Comment: @tao.hong - there must be something else going on in IE7 because my code works perfectly fine in IE7 here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/fRAGr/

Comment: I doubt the same /thing. Is there a function force IE7 to rebuilt the HTML (or refresh)?

Comment: @tao.hong - you have to write legal HTML/JS and your problem will go away.  See the rewrite of your code that I've added to my answer and the demo that works fine in IE7.

Comment: @tao.hong - added second rewrite version that just constructs HTML into a string (a bit simpler to comprehend) before creating the whole table all at once.

Answer (score 1):

Only append whole html elements.

```
$('<table class="leslie" border="0" align="center"><tr><th width="5">Lesile Matrix:</th></tr></table>').appendTo('.table');         
$('<tr><td><input type="text" size="5" name="a" value="0" id="id_a"/></td></tr>').appendTo('.leslie');
```

If you need to append an unknown number of rows, do it this way instead:

```
var strHTML = '<table class="leslie" border="0" align="center"><tr><th width="5">Lesile Matrix:</th></tr>';
// simulate a loop adding rows
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    strHTML += '<tr><td><input type="text" size="5" name="a" value="0" id="id_a"/></td></tr>';
}

$($.parseHTML(strHTML)).appendTo(".table");
```

Comment: @tao.hong Looks fine, other than you aren't taking into account anything anyone here has told you and the fact that it won't do what you expect it to do for those same reasons.

Comment: @tao.hong It requires jQuery 1.8.0 http://jsfiddle.net/vqdV4/1/ if you want it to work with 1.7.2, use this: http://jsfiddle.net/vqdV4/2/

Comment: Also, you were still missing the closing `"</table>"`

Comment: I have the close tag. Once I added "$(strHTML).appendTo('.table');​" My browser does not work...

Comment: If it "does not work" more than likely a js error is being thrown. What is it?